# stack around the variable...was corrupted

Tags: c++, stack, printf

I have a simple function that writes some data to a new file. It works, and the file is written, but I get the above mentioned error while debugging in MSVS Express 2013.

```
void writeSpecToFile(const char *fname); //in header file.

char myChar [20];
sprintf(myChar, "aa%03daa%daa", i1, i2);
const char* new_char = myChar;
writeSpecToFile(myChar);
```

As seen, I simply insert some variables into a string using sprintf (works fine). Now whether I pass myChar or new_char, it still gives me the corruption error.

What went wrong?

Comment: There's not enough space in your buffer `myChar` to store the data you're writing there

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, that one is a running gag on SO, whether there's an additional `not` or not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why did you declare you character buffer a size of 20?  More than likely the `sprintf` placed more characters than that can fit in myChar.

Instead, use

1. safer constructs such as std::ostringstream or
2. at the very least, declare you char arrays much bigger than you would expect (not the best way, but would at least not have had the error occur).

If you're going along the "guess the biggest size for my array"
    route, the last thing you want to do is attempt to count, right down
    to the last character, how big to make the buffer.  If you're off by a single byte, that can cause a crash.

Comment: Most of the code was not written be me, and I would like to modify it as less as possible.

Comment: Problem solved...but I thought char[20] is going to give me 20 characters...I have only 15 characters...so there should have been no problem.

Comment: `I have only 15 characters`  We don't know what you have in terms of the actual character string.  What we *do* know is what Deduplicator pointed out in his answer.  You need at least 23 characters to size the buffer to ensure any data that fits that format won't overflow the buffer.

Comment: BTW: I think it's better to suggest an appropriate small change avoiding the dangers, than a whole-program-transform.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming 32-bit `int`, printing one with `%d` will yield a maximum of 8 visible characters.

Your format-string also contains 6 literal `a`-characters, and we should not forget the 0-terminator.

All in all: `2*8+6+1 = 23 > 20` !!

Your buffer must be at least 23 byte big, unless there are other undisclosed input-restrictions.

Personally, I would give it a round 32.

Also, better use [`snprintf`](//man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) and optionally verify the full string did actually fit (if it does not fit you get a shortened string, so no catastrophe).

```
char myChar [32];
snprintf(myChar, sizeof myChar, "aa%03daa%daa", i1, i2);
```

Beware that [the Microsoft implementation](//msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93.aspx) is non-conforming and does not guarantee 0-termination.

Comment: Agree with *everything* in this post, but will point out that `snprintf` et al have weird "non-standard" behavior on MSVC. Read the documentation carefully to make sure you understand how it works and make sure your code handles the ugly platform-specific differences if you are targeting multiple platforms.

Comment: @NikBougalis: Aye, they screwed up their return values really bad. Still, I myself would prefer using a free, conforming (and thus not badly broken) replacement for the MSVC `snprintf`.